# Install Moai SDK 1.0 and create android project

Tags: android, sdk, moai

I installed:

1. Android SDK
2. Cygwin
3. Ant
4. Android NDK
5. Java
6. Eclipse
7. and Download Moai SDK

Add in system variable `PATH` $JavaDir and $AntDir
Add `JAVA_HOME`
Create Device in Android Emulator 2.1,2.2 and 2.3

run in ant directory sdk-setup.bat and after that run run-host.bat

And I see this error

> file not found .?*
>   file not found .?*
>   file not found .?*
>   file not found .?*
>   file not found .?*
>   FIND: invalid key
>   FIND: invalid key
>   file not found .?*
>   file not found .?*

OS Windows 7/32bit

Comment: You should try asking on the Moai forum as people may not check stack overflow.

http://getmoai.com/forums/

Comment: I did it. http://getmoai.com/forums/permission-denied-t542/ but people not answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are receiving these errors because cygwin cannot find files or most probably your search paths are invalid.

you forgot to **add cygwin directory to PATH**. It has to be in first before any windows paths.

Answer (score 1):

This question is now answered on the Moai forums - sorry for the delay. The long and the short is that the find command syntax differs on Mac and Cygwin, so I have proposed a workaround on the Moai forums. For an upcoming SDK release, we'll tweek the scripts to make sure that they are more Windows-compatible.

Comment: thanks sean :) I decided to have a problem. I change command find on /usr/bin/find ... and this work :)